# Why does one of this loop not work for incrementing a hash table?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

So I have two loops. They use a key on a hashtable. If there is nothing in that key, store 1. If there is something store whatever there is plus 1.

```
   for(int i=0; i<nums1.length; i++) {
        Integer count = nums_hash.get(i);
            if (count == null) {
               nums_hash.put(nums1[i], 1);
            }
            else {
               nums_hash.put(nums1[i], count+1);
             }
      }
```

This first one does not work but the following works perfectly fine:

```
      for(int i = 0; i < nums1.length; i++)
        {
            if(nums_hash.containsKey(nums1[i])) {
               nums_hash.put(nums1[i],nums_hash.get(nums1[i])+1);
               }

            else nums_hash.put(nums1[i], 1);
       }
```

I would like to understand an explanation for this.

Comment: So you wonder why `nums_hash.get(i)` and `nums_hash.get(nums1[i])` behave differently? Then I wonder why ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second line of code should be

```
Integer count = nums_hash.get(nums1[i]);
```

Comment: It happens to us all. You may want to consider removing your question since it doesn't add much to the community.

Comment: I tried but now that is has answers it cannot be deleted. Truthfully, I checked it multiple times to see if it had some stupid mistake like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same key all the way through the code. A good way to avoid this is to not evaluate it repeatedly as you have. e.g.

```
Integer key = nums1[i];
```

A cleaner way of writing this code so you avoid incorrect duplication of code is to use a for-each loop and [Map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
for(Integer i : nums1)
  nums_hash.compute(i, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Note: using compute is thread safe for a thread safe Map.

Comment: `p` can never be null. `merge(i, 1, (p, v) -> p + v)` will do it.

Comment: @Andreas good point, wrong method. The original code doesn't assume the value already exists.

Comment: Wrong `compute()` signature. It should only have two parameters. And it is `v` you need to null check, since `p` is replaced by `k`, which you won't be using.

Comment: @Andreas Or `merge(i, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

The First one doesn't work because instead of passing the value of nums[i] to the get method you are passing the value of i. Change the second line of the first code to

```
Integer count = nums_hash.get(nums[i]);
```